# Need help making jQuery loop for basic .fadeIn()/.fadeOut() slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, slider

I'm new to jQuery and am having trouble figuring out the right way to loop a set of code for a basic carousel/banner rotator. I've tried a few versions of "for" statements and .each(), but I can't get it to work on my own so I'm reaching out for help.

Here's my code so far:

```
$('.next-1').click(function () {
    $('.featured-1').fadeOut(500,function(){
            $('.featured-2').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.featured-2').toggleClass("hide");
        });
    });
});
$('.next-2').click(function () {
    $('.featured-2').fadeOut(500,function(){
            $('.featured-3').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.featured-3').toggleClass("hide");
        });
    });
});
```

And then a similar code block for going back within the slider:

```
$('.prev-2').click(function () {
    $('.featured-2').fadeOut(500,function(){
            $('.featured-1').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.featured-2').toggleClass("hide");
        });
    });
});
$('.prev-3').click(function () {
    $('.featured-3').fadeOut(500,function(){
            $('.featured-2').fadeIn(500,function(){
        $('.featured-3').toggleClass("hide");
        });
    });
});
```

This code does work right now, I just don't want to have to output so many unnecessary lines of code when I know I could loop it. I'd like to be able to loop until there are no more "featured-n" divs to cycle through (being able to cycle around to the beginning would be great too!)

Here's the PHP/HTML I'm using to generate each "featured-n" div block:

```
function home_slider_loop() {

$count = 0;
query_posts ('tag=slider');

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$count++;
?>

        <div class="featured-post featured-<?php echo $count; if ($count>1) { echo ' hide';}?>">
            <div class="featured-header">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><h1 class="featured-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
                <p class="author">Written by Evan Luzi</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrap">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'slider-image')); ?></a>
            <div class="slider-nav">
                <div class="featured-prev prev-<?php echo $count; ?>"></div>
                <div class="featured-next next-<?php echo $count; ?>"></div>
            </div><!--End Navigation-->
            </div><!--End Image <?php echo $count; ?>-->
            <div class="featured-footer">
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
            <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" >Read more</a>
            </div>
        </div><!--End Featured <?php echo $count; ?>-->

<?php 

endwhile;
endif;
}
```

Here's a sample of one of the static HTML outputs (just imagine this iterated several times with the "featured-n" classes incrementing:

```
<div class="featured-1">
            <div class="featured-header">
                <a href="http://www.tbabdev.com/?p=27" title="5 Useful Cinematography Apps for iOS You Should Download Today"><h1 class="featured-title">5 Useful Cinematography Apps for iOS You Should Download Today</h1></a>
                <p class="author">Written by Evan Luzi</p>
            </div>
            <div class="image-wrap">
            <a href="http://www.tbabdev.com/?p=27" title="5 Useful Cinematography Apps for iOS You Should Download Today"><img width="1018" height="416" src="http://www.tbabdev.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/cinematography-apps-8-hero.jpg" class="slider-image wp-post-image" alt="cinematography-apps-8-hero" /></a>
            <div class="slider-nav">
                <div class="featured-prev prev-1"></div>
                <div class="featured-next next-1"></div>
            </div><!--End Navigation-->
            </div><!--End Image 1-->
            <div class="featured-footer">
                <p>The devices we have in our pockets, the ones that can run these apps, these are the new leathermans. They have everything we need. They eliminate the need to carry paper manuals and enable us to do complex timelapse calculations in a fraction of the time as a paper and pen.</p>
            <a class="more-link" href="http://www.tbabdev.com/?p=27" alt="5 Useful Cinematography Apps for iOS You Should Download Today" >Read more</a>
            </div>
        </div><!--End Featured 1-->
```

You can see the code in action at http://www.tbabdev.com/

Thank you in advance for your help and please be kind to a n00b :)

Comment: Could you please show the rendered HTML (as seen by your browser, not the PHP)? And, by 'slider' do you mean '[carousel](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html)' (the link to illustrate what I'm asking, not intended as an 'answer' as such)?

Comment: @DavidThomas Sure thing. Edited the post above to add in the rendered HTML. And yes I did mean a carousel. If you go to http://www.tbabdev.com/ you'll see what I'm talking about (hover over the big banner image)

Comment: just clarifying, so you're making a loop so that you can attach click handlers to every single blog post within your carousel?

Comment: Pretty much. Is that too inefficient?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this :

```
$('.nav .prev').click(function(){

    activeBlock = $('.featured.active');
    prevBlock = activeBlock.prev('.featured');

    activeBlock.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        prevBlock.fadeIn().addClass('active');
    }).removeClass('active');

});
$('.nav .next').click(function(){

    activeBlock = $('.featured.active');
    nextBlock = activeBlock.next('.featured');

    activeBlock.fadeOut('slow',function(){
        nextBlock.fadeIn().addClass('active');
    }).removeClass('active');

});
```

Html

```
<div class="nav">
   <div class="prev">&nbsp;</div>
   <div class="next">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div class="featured-post featured <?php if($count>1) echo 'hide' ?>">

    <div class="featured-header">
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><h1 class="featured-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1></a>
        <p class="author">Written by Evan Luzi</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image-wrap">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('full', array('class' => 'slider-image')); ?></a>

    </div>
    <!--End Image <?php echo $count; ?>-->

    <div class="featured-footer">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        <a class="more-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" >Read more</a>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
$('.featured-next, .featured-prev').click(function () {
    //find out if the clicked element is a prev or next element, extract the last part, will be useful later        
    var direction = $(this).hasClass("featured-next") ? "next" : "prev";

    //select the ".featured-n" block which is the super-parent of clicked element
    var $fullBlock = $(this).closest('div[class^="featured-"]'); //or add a class here to make your life easier

    //fade out full block
    $fullBlock.fadeOut(500, function () {
        //search for the next element and show it
        //note that $fullBlock.next() => $fullBlock["next"]() => $fullBlock[direction]() 
        $fullBlock[direction]().fadeIn(500, function () {
            //toggle the class "hide" of the element next to fullBlock
            $(this).toggleClass("hide");
        });
    });
});
```

**Explanation:**

- You can join up both `prev` and `next` events together.
- Then, you have to check if its a `next` or a `prev` element. Set that to a variable called `direction`. We'll be using this to find out if we have to use `prev()` or `next()` when we're trying to `fadeIn` `featured-n` divs.
- Find the parent with the class set to `featured-n` (in your case its the superparent). **It might be better if you give a common class to all these elements so that we can stop using `'div[class^="featured-"]'` selector, which is slightly inefficient.**
- Fade out the superparent.
- In the callback, based on the `direction` variable, we'll have to decide if the carousel is gonna go to prev block or next block, something like this :

  ```
   if(direction === "prev")
   {
     $fullBlock.prev().fadeIn(//your code)
   }
   else
   {
     $fullBlock.next().fadeIn(//your code)
   }
  ```

  You must also know that, in an object like this :

  ```
   var data = {"name" : "Blah Blah"}
  ```

  To get the "Blah Blah" out, we can say

  ```
   data.name
  ```

  or we could say :

  ```
   data["name"]
  ```

  So based on this, in our situation, instead of

  ```
   $fullBlock.prev()
  ```

  Or we could say

  ```
  $fullBlock["prev"]()
  ```

  Which is what `direction` variable contains. So finally, we could do this to select the next/prev element based on what was clicked : 
     $fullBlockdirection
- Show the prev/next element.
- Add/remove "hide" class.

Hope this helped!